# What are the primary differences between IPv4 and IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I understand that the pool of IP addresses has been increased (32bit to 128bit).

Are there some other primary differences between the two?

Comment: This question is too broad. IPv4 and IPv6 are  similar but different protocols.

Comment: what is the primary difference between stackoverflow and wikipedia?

Comment: Too broad *and* off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv4 uses a 32-bit address scheme, allowing for 2^32 different addresses. IPv6 uses a 128-bit address scheme, allowing for 2^128 different addresses.

The biggest improvement of IPv6 was the huge increase of possible addresses. There are some other important technological changes though:

- No more NAT (Network Address Translation)
- Auto-configuration
- No more private address collisions
- Better multicast routing
- Simpler header format
- Simplified, more efficient routing
- True quality of service (QoS), also called "flow labeling"
- Built-in authentication and privacy support
- Flexible options and extensions
- Easier administration (say good-bye to DHCP)

[Source](http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Internet/ipv6_ipv4_difference.html)